# my react code is working but when i refresh the page i get TypeError: Cannot read property 'Location' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

Starting with GamePage, it provides 2 routes which renders the components GameList and GameDetailPage. Both work fine at first but When i refresh the page for Gamelist component, it still rerenders the page but when i refresh the page for GameDetailPage,  i get the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'Location' of undefined. I do not understand why it is unable to fetch data from state whenever i refresh.

gamepage.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import GamesList from "../../components/games-list/game-list.component";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import GameDetailPage from "../gamedetailpage/gamedetailpage.component";
import {firestore,convertCollectionsSnapshotToMap} from '../../firebase/firebase.utils'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {updateFootballGames} from '../../redux/games/games.actions'

class GamePage extends React.Component {

  unsubscribeFromSnapshot=null;

  //whenever the component mounts the state will be updated with the football games.
  componentDidMount(){
    const {updateFootballGames}=this.props
    const gameRef=firestore.collection('footballgames')
    gameRef.onSnapshot(async snapshot=>{
      const collectionsMap=convertCollectionsSnapshotToMap(snapshot)
      updateFootballGames(collectionsMap)
    })
  }
  render() {
    const { match } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="game-page">
        <h1>games page</h1>
        <Route exact path={`${match.path}`} component={GamesList} />
        <Route path={`${match.path}/:linkUrl`} component={GameDetailPage}
         />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps=state=>({
  games:state.games.games
})

const mapDispatchToProps=dispatch=>({
  updateFootballGames:collectionsMap=>
  dispatch(updateFootballGames(collectionsMap))
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(GamePage);
```

gamedetailpage.component.jsx

```
  import React from "react";
    import { connect } from "react-redux";
    import GamePreview from '../../components/game-preview/game-preview.component'
    import GameDetails from '../../components/game-details/game-details.component'

const GameDetailPage = (props) => {
    const {games, match} = props
    const urlparam =match.params.linkUrl
    // const games_array = Object.entries(games)
    const gameObj=games[urlparam]
    console.log('prop',gameObj)


    return (
      <div className="game-list"> 
          <GameDetails game = {gameObj}/>
      </div>

    );

};




const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  games: state.games.games,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GameDetailPage);
```

game_details.component.jsx

```
import React from 'react';


const GameDetails = (props) => {
    console.log(props.game.Location)

    return(
    <div>
    Location:{props.game.Location}
    <br/>
    Price:{props.game.Price}
    </div>

    )
}

export default GameDetails;
```

gamelist.component.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import './game-list.styles.scss'
import GamePreview from "../game-preview/game-preview.component";
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

const GameList=(props)=>{
    const {games}=props
    console.log(games)
    const game_list=Object.entries(games)
    console.log(game_list)
    return (
      <div className="game-list">
        {game_list.map(game => 
                <GamePreview game = {game[1]}/>)}
      </div>

    );
  }

const mapStateToProps=state=>({
  games:state.games.games
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GameList);
```

gamepreview.component.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import "./game-preview.styles.scss";
import { withRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";


import GamePreviewDetail from "../game-preview-detail/game-preview-detail.component";

const GamePreview = (props) => {
  const { Location, Time, linkUrl, Price } = props.game;
  const { history, match } = props;
  return (
    <div
      className="game-preview"
      onClick={() => history.push(`${match.url}/${linkUrl}`)}
    >
      <div className="game-preview-image">
        <p>Picture goes here</p>
      </div>
      {/* <GamePreviewDetail name = {Location} price={Price}/> */}
      <p>Location:{Location}</p>
      <p>Price:{Price}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withRouter(GamePreview);
```

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
//import dependencies
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
//import pages
import HomePage from './pages/homepage/homepage'
import GamesPage from './pages/gamespage/gamespage'
import SignInSignUp from './pages/signin-signup-page/signin-signup-page'

import GameDetailPage from "./pages/gamedetailpage/gamedetailpage.component";

import Header from './components/header/header.component';

import { auth, createUserProfileDocument } from './firebase/firebase.utils';

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      currentUser: null
    } 
  }

  unsubscribeFromAuth = null

  componentDidMount() {
  this.unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async userAuth => {
    if (userAuth) {
      const userRef = await createUserProfileDocument(userAuth);
      // check if the snapshot has changed (subscribe)
      // get the user that we just created or that already exists in the db
      userRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        this.setState({
          currentUser: {
            id: snapshot.id,
            ...snapshot.data()}
        })
      })  
    } else {
      this.setState({currentUser: userAuth})
    }

    })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth();
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Header currentUser = {this.state.currentUser}/>
         <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />  
          <Route path="/games" component={GamesPage} />  
          <Route exact path="/signin" component={SignInSignUp} />  
        </Switch>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try using [`useParams`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/useparams) hook instead. Then capturing any changes of `linkUrl` with [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook. Also introducing `gameObj` with [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

> `useParams` returns an object of key/value pairs of URL parameters. Use it to access `match.params` of the current `<Route>`.
>
> If you're familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think of `useEffect` Hook as `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount` combined.

Try to modify `<GameDetailPage />` component as the following:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
// other imports

const GameDetailPage = (props) => {
   const { games } = props;
   let { linkUrl } = useParams();
   const [ gameObj, setGameObj ] = useState(null);

   useEffect(() => {
      if (games) {
         const newGameObj = games[linkUrl];
         console.log('game object', newGameObj);

         setGameObj(newGameObj);
      }
   }, [games, linkUrl]);

   return <div className="game-list"> 
      { gameObj && <GameDetails game={ gameObj } /> }
   </div>
}
```

**+1 - `null` check:**

Also you can see a `null` check in the return statement for `gameObj` which helps rendering only that case once you have a value in `games` array with found `linkUrl` value.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with how the person accesses params.  Its just how and when the data is made available to use to the component

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri There is quite a different solutions how `urlparam` and `gameObj` are introduced in the function component body in the question. Usually I like to use hooks because that's the suggested way from the documentation. Several times if we follow the suggested ways then issues can be eliminated easily. So do you think something is wrong around `mapStateToProps`?

Comment: Agreed but the issue is because the data i,e game is being fetched asynchronously in another component and if you visit the link directly on refresh the data won't be present

Comment: Then probably a simple `null` check like `games &&` would do the job in the original code. Anyway I extended my answer within the `useEffect` by checking if `games` has values. I will leave here my answer, maybe helps somehow the OP. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Ideally in such scenarios a loading state is a good way to improve UX rather than a null check but yes that would work too